# supabase flutter get multiple data (JSON object requested, multiple (or no) rows returned)

Tags: flutter, dart, postgrest, supabase

I am trying to print out multiple data from Supabase using flutter but it just isn't working

```
getResponse(String uid) async {
    await client
        .from("privChatRoom")
        .select()
        .eq('userID', uid)
        .single()
        .execute()
        .then((value) {
      if (value.error == null) {
        print('value.data: ${value.data}');
      } else {
        print(value.error.message.toString());
        print(value.error.hint.toString());
      }
    });
  }
```

This is the error i get whenever i run this function

```
I/flutter ( 2326): JSON object requested, multiple (or no) rows returned
I/flutter ( 2326): null
```

I have multiple row with the same uid that i want to get please how do i get it

EDIT: Found the answer i just had to remove `.single()`

Answer (score 3):

Just here to clarify.

If you use `single()` filter, your result has to return 1 and only 1 result, and otherwise it will fail. If you want multiple return values, you can just get rid of the `single()` like this:

```dart
getResponse(String uid) async {
    await client
        .from("privChatRoom")
        .select()
        .eq('userID', uid)
        .execute()
        .then((value) {
      if (value.error == null) {
        print('value.data: ${value.data}');
      } else {
        print(value.error.message.toString());
        print(value.error.hint.toString());
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If are expecting a result to not have a single response, call the query without `.single()`. You should get an empty result then.

Or maybe the `uid` value doesn't exit in your database!

Try to replace `.single()` with `.limit(1)`,

Don't forget this function returns an array! So you have to get the data like this `value.data[0]`, If no data exist then the `value.data` will be an empty array `[]`.

If you expect to get 0 rows though you might want to use `.maybeSingle()` instead.

Read this:
https://postgrest.org/en/stable/api.html#singular-or-plural

Comment: I like this answer. I will use maybeSingle(). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a flutter user, but using `.single()` should work the same way as in the Javascript client.

`.limit(1)` <= returns a single record as an array
`[{id:123,firstname:'Harry',lastname:'Styles'}]`

`.single()` <= returns a single record as an object
`{id:123,firstname:'Harry',lastname:'Styles'}`

Comment: Please make sure your answers are unique. Your answer seems very similar to one of the previous answers. I suggest you read [answer]